# Trigger Post_save signal on M2M field

Tags: python, django

This code should add items to an index every time a new object is created. It works, but does not realise the M2M field is being created.

I believe the signal doesn't "see" tags (as it's an M2M field).

In other words:

- adds the title field only to index when object is "CREATED"
- only adds the M2M relations to index when "SAVE" is clicked

FWIW, this is indexing for elastic search.

## Models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Title", max_length=10000, blank=True)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)

    def get_grouped_tags(self):
        tag = self.tag.order_by('taglevel')
        grouped_tags = {
            tag_level: [
                { 'name': tag_of_level.name, 'taglevel': tag_of_level.taglevel, }
                for tag_of_level in tags_of_level
            ] for tag_level, tags_of_level
            in groupby(tag, lambda tag: tag.taglevel)
        }
        return grouped_tags

    def to_search(self):
        d = {
            "tags": self.grouped_tags(),
            "title": self.title
        }
        return ItemIndex(meta={'id': self.id}, **d)

    def indexing(self):
        obj = ItemIndex(
            meta={'id': self.id},
            title=self.title,
            typeItem=self.get_typeItem_display()
        )
        obj.save()
        return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)

def update_search(instance, **kwargs):
    instance.to_search().save()

def remove_from_search(instance, **kwargs):
    instance.to_search().delete()

post_save.connect(update_search, sender=Item)
post_save.connect(update_search, sender=Tag)
pre_delete.connect(remove_from_search, sender=Item)
pre_delete.connect(remove_from_search, sender=Tag)
m2m_changed.connect(update_search, sender=Item)
```

## Search.py

```
connections.create_connection()

class ItemIndex(DocType):
    title = String()
    class Meta:
        index = 'Item-index'


def bulk_indexing():
    ItemIndex.init()
    es = Elasticsearch()
    bulk(client=es, actions=(b.indexing() for b in models.Item.objects.all().iterator()))


def _search(title):
    s = Search().filter('term', title=title.text)
    response = s.execute()
    return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Was related to the `m2m_changed`. I needed to create a "through" method.

Only change needed was this:

```
m2m_changed.connect(update_search, sender=Item.tag.through)
```